# when there are some classes which may not exist, how should I manage them in an XxxAutoConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```java
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId> // it provide AFactory.class
            <version>1</version>
            <option>true</option>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId> // it provide BFactory.class
            <version>1</version>
            <option>true</option>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

In my starter project, I will write a `XxxAutoConfiguration` that uses AFactory or BFactory.

I've tried:

```java
@Configuration
public class XxxAutoConfiguration {
    
    private AFactory aFactory;
    private BFactory bfactory;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setaFactory(AFactory aFactory) {
        this.aFactory = aFactory;
    }

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setBfactory(BFactory bfactory) {
        this.bfactory = bfactory;
    }
    

    @Bean
    public Something something(){
        if(aFactory != null){
            return new Something(aFactory);
        }else if(bfactory != null){
            return new Something(bfactory);
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

I know I can write three AutoConfiguration respectively with `@ConditionalOnBean(AFactory.class)`, `@ConditionalOnBean(BFactory.class)` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(....)` to solve the problem, but it's
far from elegant... do you have any good solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try adding `@PostConstruct` to the `configure()` method, so it actually gets called. --- Why would you expect `configure()` to be called otherwise? Did you **read the documentation** for [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)? It doesn't say *anything* about any `configure()` method.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your answer, I know `@Configuration` is to create Bean .. emm... I will change my problem make it more clear.. thanks

Comment: But there is no code in the `XxxAutoConfiguration` class to *create Bean*, so if you know that is the purpose of `@Configuration` classes, why even use `@Configuration`?

Comment: @Andreas I've changed my problem.. the `configure` method is just an example... emmm And when I write it I am not careful enough....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing code that uses a class that may not exist on the classpath at runtime is not  good idea. Writing the code so it doesn't cause `NoClassDefFoundError` is troublesome.

The standard Spring Boot way can e.g. be seen in the source code of [`DataSourceConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration.java).

In your case, you can do this:

```java
abstract class XxxAutoConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnBean(AFactory.class)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Something.class)
    @AutoConfigureOrder(1) // Try AFactory first
    static class ASomething {
        private AFactory aFactory;

        @Autowired
        void setaFactory(AFactory aFactory) {
            this.aFactory = aFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        Something something() {
            return new Something(this.aFactory);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnBean(BFactory.class)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Something.class)
    @AutoConfigureOrder(2) // Try BFactory second
    static class BSomething {
        @Bean
        Something something(BFactory bFactory) {
            return new Something(bFactory);
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, you can do it using `@Autowired` or using a parameter, either way should work.

In case both `AFactory` and `BFactory` are present on the classpath, you can e.g. use `@AutoConfigureOrder` to specify which one wins, as shown here. There are other `@ConditionalXxx` annotations for more complex ways.

The `XxxAutoConfiguration` class is really just a pseudo-package for keeping it all together.